# MSI Installation Paths

Tags: msbuild, windows-installer

I've implemented the MSBuild Community Tasks from tigris to my C# Project.

My Problem is that im not alone working on this project, but i dont want everyone to install the MSBuild Community Task on his local PC.

Without MSBuild Community Task you're not able to compile the project.

So my idea was to make a small workaround, i want to include the Install-Files to my project and copy it with a precompile-command to the MSI-Install-destination

But i dont know where the MSI saves its files.

Does anyone know how to find out where the MSI File copies the included file to?

Or does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved my problem executing the MSI-File with the command-shell, I've changed the TargetDir to C:\Temp\MyMSI and the generated folder-structure told my where it's saving the files to.

> msiexec /a "MyMsi.msi" /qn
>   TARGETDIR=C:\Temp\MyMSI